# Entity Framework GET Web Service Throwing Errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, entity-framework

I have this GREAT WCF service that returns Data from EF.

```
public class HistoryDataService : DataService<HistoryEntities>
{
    #region Public Methods

    public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
    {
        config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.All);
        config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("*", ServiceOperationRights.All);
        config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3;
    }

    [WebGet]
    public IQueryable<History> GetHistoriesById(int recordId)
    {
        return CurrentDataSource.Histories.Where(d => d.RecordId == recordId);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

I have other services that I added something like:

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "eventdetails/{id}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
```

to make it more of a traditional RESTful service, however, when I add it I get various errors like:

```
... both defines a ServiceContract and inherits a ServiceContract from type System.Data.Services.IRequestHandler.`
```

How do I add this property or is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

It would save you a lot of time to use WCF Data Services or OData as it is called.  You'll get both JSON and XML output for your web service response. Your choice. : )

[WCF Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/bb931106.aspx%27)